# React js- pass value to other form and use in class

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

so I've got two files.

First file:

```
btn1_handle = (id_value: any) => {
receiveID(id_value);
```

Second file:

```
    export const receiveID = (id_value: any) => {
    console.log(id_value);
    this.setState{ii: id_value};
}
```

But I can't change the state, because the exported const is outside the class. How can I change the state?

Comment: Can you show where you;re defining your state?

Comment: And secondly, it will be this.setState({ii: id_value))

Answer (score 0):

this way not working, you can update state only from current component. so move `receiveID` function to your component class.

**Edit:**

you should use React Context.
take a look at this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-api-example-0ghhy

Comment: But I can't export the function, if I move it to the class, right?

Comment: yes, right. but do you need to export this function? you can't use it. because it not possible in react. if you want to control state from another file, you can use context and hooks

Comment: I use the function to get the id from the other page... SO page 1 sends the id to page2 with this function

Comment: you cannot do this, use context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: ok, but it doesn't explain, how to share it over multiple pages/files